# how to detect if photo is mostly a document?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I think i am looking for something simpler than detecting a document boundaries in a photo. I am only trying to flag photos which are mostly of documents rather than just a normal scene photo. is this an easier problem to solve?

Comment: Sorry, I had to link this here: https://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: What characterises a photo that is mostly of a document, compared to a "normal scene" photo? Perhaps try to collect a statistically meaningful sample of such pictures, so that you can analyze them and learn how to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are the documents mostly white? If so, you could analyse the images for white content above a certain percentage. Generally text documents only have about 10% printed content on them in total.